# Can Logia Devil Fruit Users get hot or cold?

Tags: one-piece

Can Logia Devil Fruit users get hot or cold?

Examples:

- Mera Mera No Mi *(Fire Devil Fruit)* - If this user were to be walking on an island of snow, would they be able to control their body temperature and stay warm (internally)? Or would they get cold like a normal person?
- Yuki Yuki no Mi *(Snow Devil Fruit)* - If this user were to be walking on a desert island, would they be able to control their body temperature and stay cool (internally)? Or would they get hot like a normal person?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Anime and Manga StackExchange, Denna! Not-a-One-Piece-reader here, but I have a question regarding the clarity of your post : By "control their body temperature", what do you mean? By making use of their Devil Fruit powers as they usually do (e.g summoning Fire / Snow) or by an intern process?

Comment: I mean by internally staying warm or cold.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think they get hot or cold. Some of them can even change the climate around them

When Ace came to Drum Kingdom (Snow Island) there was no snow.

[image]
<sub>Chapter 154 To Alabasta</sub>

Also remember Akainu and Aokiji battle, they divide the climate on the Island. In ten day they permanently changed the weather on Punk Hazard, turning one side into a frozen wasteland and other side left in a blaze

Smoker also doesn't seems to get hot or cold in Alabasta or Punk Hazard. He wore his jacket the same way on those island - he left it unbuttoned. The same goes to Crocodile when he was in Freezing Hell floor and Blazing Hell floor in Impel Down. Although he only there for a moment.

Comment: But we do see smoker experiencing cold at punk hazard as in conclusive evidence from his outfit ? And we do have other kind of logia types other than the dichotomy of heat and cold.

Comment: no, he left his jacket unbuttoned, when Luffy, Law, and Zorro properly wore them, but then again, he still left his shirt unbuttoned when he was in Tashigi body

Comment: But does he normally wear a jacket at all? Not just that , the probability of them changing the weather is restricted to just to a select few?

Comment: I'll edit to clarify

Comment: I understand that they can change the temperatures around them, but can they change their temperatures internally to stay warm or cold? Without actually showing the use of their powers openly.

Comment: like I said, Smoker and Crocodile didn't seems to get hot or cold in extreme temperature location. They did it without actually showing the use of their powers openly. They just casually walk in there

Comment: Smoker is definitely not relying on his powers to survive cold. (Spoiler) When he and Tashigi changed bodies, he lost all of his powers, yet his jacket was still unbuttoned